# how do i add ngClass in angular need to show status active red and other should be inactive black

Tags: angular

how do I add ngClass in angular need to show current status active red color and others should be inactive black?

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of status_history; let i = index">
  <div [ngClass]="checkStatusClass(i)">
      <span class="material-icons">check_circle</span>
      <span class="status_font">{{item?.invoice_status?.data[0]?.status}}</span>
      <div class="history-font">{{item?.updated_at}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of status_history; let i = index">
  <div [ngClass]="{'icons_inactive' : (i+1) === status_history.length, 'icons_active': (i+1) !== status_history.length}">
      <span class="material-icons">check_circle</span>
      <span class="status_font">{{item?.invoice_status?.data[0]?.status}}</span>
      <div class="history-font">{{item?.updated_at}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: not working @arbghl

Comment: when you say latest state is active, does that mean that it will be the first element in the status_history array?

if that is the case then you can do <div [ngClass]="{'icons_active' : i === 0, 'icons_inactive': i !== 0}">

Comment: @Abid "not working" is not a response, explain your problem or detail your question. This `ngClass` statement as far as I can tell is equal to the function you wrote

Answer (score -1):

Try this (untested):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of status_history; let i = index">
  <div class="checkStatusClass(i)">
      <span class="material-icons">check_circle</span>
      <span class="status_font">{{item?.invoice_status?.data[0]?.status}}</span>
      <div class="history-font">{{item?.updated_at}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this does work, using functions in your template is discouraged for performance reasons.